# Module has no attribute error when unittest is run in python

Tags: python, dbus, python-unittest

```
import avahi
import dbus

__author__ = 'michael'


class AvahiServicePublisher():

    def __init__(self):
        self.group = None
        bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        server = dbus.Interface(
            bus.get_object(
                avahi.DBUS_NAME,
                avahi.DBUS_PATH_SERVER),
            avahi.DBUS_INTERFACE_SERVER)

        self.group = dbus.Interface(
            bus.get_object(avahi.DBUS_NAME,
                           server.EntryGroupNew()),
            avahi.DBUS_INTERFACE_ENTRY_GROUP)

    def publish(self, name, port, stype="_http._tcp", domain="", host="", text=""):
        self.group.AddService(avahi.IF_UNSPEC, avahi.PROTO_UNSPEC, dbus.UInt32(0),
                              name, stype, domain, host,
                              dbus.UInt16(port), text)

        self.group.Commit()

    def unpublish(self):
        self.group.Reset()
```

That's how I'm running unittest

```
python -m unittest tests.AvahiTest
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/AvahiTest.py", line 10, in setUp
    self.service_publisher = AvahiServicePublisher()
  File "avahi/AvahiServicePublisher.py", line 14, in __init__
    avahi.DBUS_NAME,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DBUS_NAME'
```

So... How can I ran unittest without this error? And what is the reason for that error?

Comment: Are you sure that the `avahi` module has the name `DBUS_NAME` in its namespace? Perhaps you override the default `avahi` module with some package you have created?